# How to print odd/even series without if-statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm writing program to list odd/even series from n elements (1,2,...n) using if-statement.
For example,

```
n = 1

Odd Series
1
3
5
7
9

Even Series
0
2
4
6
8
```

If any possible to print odd/even series without if-statement.

Comment: $n % 2 == 0 to know if an element is odd or even. But without an if statement i think you can't know.

Comment: Hello. Please post your code. Did you try to code anything? People aren't gonna write code for you, but they can help you with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. We can list odd or even series without if-condition.

We use Increment operator insteed of if-condition.

Sample code is,

```
<?php
    echo "Odd Series";
    echo "<pre>";
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
         echo ++$i;
    }
    echo "Even Series";
    echo "<pre>";
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        echo $i++;
    }
?>
```

Sample output is here,

```
Odd Series
1
3
5
7
9

Even Series
0
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: You don't need to echo the `<pre>` tag for each iteration. Once before the first loop is sufficient (and you should close it after the latter)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) with a step of 2, starting with either 0 or 1 as required:

```
echo "Odd Series\n";
foreach (range(1, 9, 2) as $v) echo "$v ";
echo "Even Series\n";
foreach (range(0, 9, 2) as $v) echo "$v ";
```

Output:

```
Odd Series
1 3 5 7 9 
Even Series
0 2 4 6 8
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JCPiO)

Answer (score 2):

We could try using a ternary expression in lieu of an `if` statement:

```
// even series
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i % 2 == 0 ? $i : "\n";
}
```

Another possibility is to just iterate the `for` loop by steps of 2:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i=$i+2) {
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using arrays, you can create the range with `range()`, and use `array_filter()` to pluck the odd or even values using bit-operators.

```
$n = 8;
$series = range(1, $n);

$odd = array_filter($series, function($value) { return $value & 1; });
$even = array_filter($series, function($value) { return !($value & 1); });

var_dump($odd, $even);
```

Then its just a matter of looping the arrays `$odd` and `$even`.

```
echo "Odd values: \n";
foreach ($odd as $v) {
    echo $v."\n";
}

echo "Even values: \n";
foreach ($even as $v) {
    echo $v."\n";
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/J9Dio